# T-SQL fill database by procedure from another database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a procedure call FILLTABLE in DB1, that procedure control the insert in DB1.table1, and I have all data in DB2.table1, so basicaly I need fill DB1.table1 by procededure FILLTABLE from BD2.table1 but filter data DB2.table1

Eg:

```
Execute BD1.dbo.FILLTABLE (
                select db2.dbo.table1.name as @name, 
                       db2.dbo.table1.phonea s @phone 
                from table1 
                where citycode = 'ca')
```

Comment: So, what's the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've got it right you should use cursor

```
DECLARE @Name varchar(1000); -- change to type of db2.dbo.table1.name
DECLARE @Phone varchar(1000); -- change to type of db2.dbo.table1.phone

DECLARE t_Cursor CURSOR FOR
select db2.dbo.table1.name, 
       db2.dbo.table1.phone
    from table1 
    where citycode = 'ca';

OPEN t_Cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM t_Cursor INTO @Name,@Phone;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
   BEGIN
      Execute BD1.dbo.FILLTABLE @Name,@Phone;
      FETCH NEXT FROM t_Cursor INTO @Name,@Phone;

   END;
CLOSE t_Cursor;
DEALLOCATE t_Cursor;
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax would be:

```
INSERT DB1.dbo.Table1
(Column1, Column2)
SELECT name, phonea
FROM db2.dbo.table1 
WHERE citycode = 'ca'
```

This is all described in the documentation for [`INSERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx).

Comment: Many thanks, but the insert must be through procedure, the example was simplified

Comment: @SergioLinoGonzálezCaqueo - So? Use the same in a SP. The basic syntax is not any different. Just wrap it in a SP.

Comment: Thanks, but can't modify the SP in DB1 and can't use insert into db1.table1 (company policies)